# How to programmatically maximize JDesktopPane

Tags: swing, maximize, jdesktoppane

I am using JDesktopPane, and I want it to be maximized when I load it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the encompassing container's layout to BorderLayout and add the JDesktopPane to the CENTER. Then set the window to maximized.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JDesktopPane jDesktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
f.add(jDesktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
...
f.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```